# Creating a sub-folder structure

Tags: powershell, subdirectory

Looking for some advice on how to use PowerShell (or some other means) to create some folders.

I have a list of around 120 products that I've allocated separate folders. (using a CSV to generate the folders)

I want each product folder to have the same subfolder structure. As shown below:

```
[Products]
├── [Product 1]
│   ├── [1. Datasheet]
│   │   ├── [1. Current]
│   │   ├── [2. Archived]
│   │   ├── [3. Legacy]
│   │   ├── [4. Draft]
│   │   └── [5. Resources]
│   ├── [2. Images]
│   ├── [3. Brochures]
│   ├── [4. Manuals]
│   └── [5. Software]
│
├── [Product 2]
│   ├── [1. Datasheet]
│   │   ├── [1. Current]
│   │   ├── [2. Archived]
│   │   ├── [3. Legacy]
│   │   ├── [4. Draft]
│   │   └── [5. Resources]
│   ├── [2. Images]
│   ├── [3. Brochures]
│   ├── [4. Manuals]
│   └── [5. Software]
:
:
```

Essentially the first layer of subfolders in each would be:

`[1. Datasheet]`, `[2. Images]`, `[3. Brochures]`, `[4. Manuals]`, `[5. Software]`

Inside each of these would be the following:

`[1.Current]`, `[2.Archived]`, `[3. Legacy]`, `[4. Draft]`, `[5. Resources]`

I don't mind doing this in stages, it's just I don't know where to begin.

Comment: You would be well-advised to think about how you would do this manually, even using the GUI, and see how you would replicate the manual steps using PowerShell. SO is not a script-writing service; you really need to show that you've put some thought into the problem and tried to come to your own answer before asking for help.

Comment: Start with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item).

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
$workingdir = 'c:\temp'

$products = Get-Content c:\temp\listofproducts.txt

$rootfolders = @(
    'Datasheet'
    'Images'
    'Brochures'
    'Manuals'
    'Software'
)

$subfolders = @(
    'Current'
    'Archived'
    'Legacy'
    'Draft'
    'Resources'
)

foreach ($product in $products) 
{
    $rootcount = 0
    foreach ($root in $rootfolders) 
    {
        $rootcount++
        $subcount = 0
        foreach ($sub in $subfolders) 
        {
            $subcount++
            mkdir (Join-Path $workingdir ("$product\$rootcount. $root\$subcount. $sub"))
        }
    }
}
```

or you could just create the first product folder then copy and paste it then rename the product

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input.

Managed to find a strategy that worked for me, so will share it in case it's of use to anyone else like me.

Used a combination of the following 3 bits of code to achieve what I needed:

```
# Create Folders from CSV

$folder = "Z:\Products\"
$name = Import-Csv Z:\Products\names.csv
Foreach ($line in $name)
{
    New-Item -path $folder -Name $line.Name -Type Directory
}
```

This above code allowed me to make a big list of folders from a CSV list made in Excel.

```
# Add a Subfolder

foreach($folder in (gci 'Z:\Products' -directory)){
    new-item -ItemType directory -Path ($folder.fullname+"\subfolder")
}
```

This above code let me populate the list of folders with subfolders. I added them one at a time.

```
# Copy a file to folder

$folders = Get-ChildItem Z:\Products
foreach ($folder in $folders.name){
Copy-Item -Path "Z:\Datasheet\changelog.txt" -Destination "Z:\Products\$folder" -Recurse
}
```

This above code allowed me to copy items to subfolder locations.